# Images are not being stored?? - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-uploads

These are my following **settings**:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/webapps/test_project/media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://192.168.0.2:8090/site_media/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'
```

These are my **model fields**:

```
large = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="images")
thumb = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="images")
```

---

What happens is... when I save a model with the images, the **paths to the images are stored** but **not the actual images**.

http://192.168.0.2:8090/site_media/images/BluUnicorn.png
http://192.168.0.2:8090/site_media/images/DarkNinja.png
...

Django behaves as if the images have been saved succesfully under the images folder, but the images are not actually there!!

---

Anyone have a clue of what I did wrong?

PS: I'm using Django 2.1+ SVN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistyped

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/webapps/test_project/media/'
```

**wrote home instead of root**

Comment: Is this an answer? If you wanted to correct your question, please edit that.